# Align image and text li in horizontal ul

Tags: html, css

I have a ul with an image and a piece of text:

```
<ul id="botoes">
    <li><a href="/o-meu-perfil"><img src="image.png"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Perguntas</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to get both items aligned horizontally, since it is an horizontal list. Therefore I'm using:

```
#botoes li{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

[image: List]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VDJQp/

Comment: Use line-height see demo http://jsfiddle.net/6uBtt/

Comment: what is height of your image ? what is padding arround of image ?

Comment: Check this [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/VDJQp/1/)

Answer (score 8):

this would solved the problem

```
#botoes li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use This CSS this will work hear is an **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/lvtrvd/dHYnu/)**

```
#botoes li{
    display: inline-block; /* changed */ 
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
    vertical-align: middle;  /* changed */ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use `line-height` for your text.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [**working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/VDJQp/1/)
(change the alignment value to: *top | bottom | middle* to your needed use)

Just add that to your **css**

```
#botoes a
{
    display: inline;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just put

```
style="display:inline-block;"
```

in tag a or tag p

example

```
<ul>
            <li>
<img height="69" width="94" src="images/guest.png"/>
<a href="#" style="display:inline-block;">
<h4>KM Plan 2016</h4>
</a>
            </li>
</ul>
```

try yourself with [JSFilddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VDJQp/68/)